# Tell jquery draggable is being dragged dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So this is a dependency of a current objective.  If we can figure this out then this and my other question will be done.

Here is the original objective: [drag marker outside map to html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424098/drag-marker-outside-map-to-html-element)

Here is the almost complete fiddle i have created: http://jsfiddle.net/y3YTS/26/

All we need to do is make it so when the "fake" marker is moving with the real marker on google maps... we tell jquery it is being dragged so the droppable zone will act properly.

1: change color since its the target

2: fire the drop event when you let go over the dropzone

my only next option is to dig through jquery source and see where I can hook in but hopefully somebody will have a bright idea!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for something like draggable's "drag" event...

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/events.html

Comment: It is drag, as seen here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ if you scroll down a bit, under the "Events" tab you'll find

Comment: I'll be duck! You're right. I've tried the drag facility a while ago and gave up. Could it be that easy... :) Thanks! +1 for that.